# Connecting to DB2/400 using GCC on Linux-PowerPC

Tags: linux, gcc, db2-400, powerpc

After a lot research, I decided to ask the question here, therefore, I have not found the answer of how I can do this.
I have a system written in C/C ++ which was designed for Linux PowerPC64 BE ( at now, I'm using Debian ) servers, and I need to connect this system to an IBM DB2/400 database, my first choice was to use unixODBC, after searching I saw the need to use a lib. for db2, but I did not find this lib, and then I did not find any other alternatives on how to make that connection.

So, how I can make this connection ?

Answer (score 3):

Linux ODBC drivers for Db2 for IBM i are available in two flavors...

Assuming you have a license for "Client Access", of which the most current incarnation is known as Access Client Solutions (ACS).  The Linux ODBC driver is in the [Linux Application Package.](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1026805)

IBM also offers a stand-a-lone product, [Db2 Connect](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.licensing.doc/doc/c0004770.html) which provides connectivity to Db2 for Z/OS, DB2 for i, and Db2 for LUW.

For C/C++ you should be good with either.  But for instance, the Python Db2 package expects Db2 Connect and doesn't work with the ACS Linux driver.